# Highchart ajax requests

Tags: php, jquery, json, highcharts

After searching the net i have decided to finally ask the question.

I am currently using PHPExcel to access xlsx data, i am also using jQuery Highcharts; both of which work when used seperately. I have found several ways of using the highcharts with different XHR methods. What i would like to know is if it is possible with the below code. I can get results to come through, the JSON that is being sent back from PHP holds 10 objects that i can see in the console. My issue lies with the data. The output inserts the last JSON object into the first slot on the xAxis and skips the first 9,

```
$(function () {                     
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Market Size & Trading Report'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Some Source'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: [],

            }],
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +'m';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#000'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Market Size',
                    style: {
                        color: '#000'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: 'Percent',
                      style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +' %';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +
                    (this.series.name == 'Percent' ? ' %' : 'm');
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 200,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 50,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Market Size',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 0,
            data: [6.7,7.0,6.8,6.6,6.4,6.8,6.5,6.3,6.3,6.4]

        }, {
            name: 'P Market Size',
            color: '#89A54E',
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [9, 8.4, 8.3,8.1,8.6,8.8,8.7,8.4,8.9,8.6]
        },{
            name: 'D Market Size',
            color: '#FFCC00',
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [1.7,1.7,1.8,1.8,2.0,1.8,1.7,1.7,1.7,1.71]
        }]
    });


    $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'http://devtest.localhost/screen-tests/excelReader/Tests/marketSizeandShareGraph.php',
                success: function (data) {
                var i;
                        $.each(data, function (k, v) {

                                chart1.xAxis[0].setCategories([v.heading]) ;

                        } );
                        }
                        } );

});
```

});

Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: What does your returned data object look like ?

Comment: Hi steve, the returned object is as follows,

Comment: [{"heading":"30-Dec"},{"heading":"06-Jan"},{"heading":"13-Jan"},{"heading":"20-Jan"},{"heading":"27-Jan"},{"heading":"03-Feb"},{"heading":"10-Jan"},{"heading":"17-Jan"},{"heading":"24-Feb"},{"heading":"03-Mar"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the categories all at once. Something like this:

```
var myCategories = [];
$.each(data, function (k, v) {
    myCategories.push(v.heading);
}
char1.xAxis[0].setCategories(myCategories);
```

Each call to setCategories will also cause the chart to be re-drawn, so calling it once is better.

Comment: Thanks, after using that fix i get a new error in the console, char1 is not defined, which i would assume it means is out of scope

Comment: Hi steve, i found that it was a typo, it worked perfectly, so to draw this to a close, i am better of creating a blank array and using the push() function?.

Thanks for you help steve :)

Comment: Each call to setCategories will redraw the chart, so calling it once is best.